# How to get neovim to use nvim-tree instead of netrw?

Tags: lua, neovim

I am trying to setup nvim-tree in my neovim plugins. I am using the Lazy package manager and I am using someone elses config as a guide on github.

In my Lazy options, I have `netrw` in teh `disabled_plugins` section and I am importing my `plugins` directory which contains the `nvim-tree` plugin, but my neovim is still using netrw and not nvim-tree. I'm not getting any error messages or anything so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here are some of the files that I think are relevant to this problem:

This is `nvim/lua/moorby/lazy.lua`:

```lua
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

local opts = {
    defaults = {
        lazy = true,
    },
    install = {
        colorscheme = { "monokai" }
    },
    rtp = {
        disabled_plugins = {
            "gzip",
            "matchit",
            "matchparen",
            "netrw",
            "netrwplugin",
            "tarplugin",
            "tohtml",
            "tutor",
            "zipplugin",
        }
    },
    change_detection = {
        enabled = true,
        notify = true,
    },
}

require("lazy").setup(
    {
        {import = "moorby.plugins"}
    },
    opts
)
```

`nvim/lua/moorby/plugins/nvim-tree.lua`

```lua
return {
    "nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua",
    filters = {
        dotfiles = true,
    },
    lazy = false
}
```

`nvim/lua/moorby/plugins/colorscheme.lua` (my colorscheme is loading fine by the way)

```lua
return {
  "tanvirtin/monokai.nvim",
  lazy = false,
  priority = 999,
  config = {},
}
```

In this screenshot, you can see netrw in the background and you can see that nvim-tree has been successfully loaded by Lazy:

[image: image of Lazy confirmed that nvim-tree plugin is loaded]

EDIT: I just noticed that the plugin being imported is `nvim-tree.LUA` not `nvim-tree.NVIM` but I tried to change this and it does not work so I think `.lua` is still correct and that is definitely the URL of the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration, you need to call `setup` function for the `nvim-tree.lua` plugin and you could also disable `netrw` in `init.lua` => see "Setup" section in https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua

```lua
-- disable netrw at the very start of your init.lua
vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
```

`nvim/lua/moorby/plugins/nvim-tree.lua`:

```lua
return {
    "nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua",
    config = function()
        require("nvim-tree").setup({
            filters = {
                dotfiles = true,
            },
            lazy = false
        })
    end,
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats it! Clearly I didn't read or understand the nvim-tree docs well enough. 

Why is it that some plugins do not require a `require(plugin).setup({})` and others do? Is it usually dependent on what the plugin does or the "size" of the plugin (size as in, does this plugin make big changes or small changes?)

Comment: Some Neovim plugins need a `setup` function to read options from the configuration or to initialize starting state.